# How to turn off cascade deleting?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, s#arp-architecture, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have class with back reference:

```
public class Employee : Entity
    {
        private string _Name;
        private string _Position;
        private Employee _SupervisorBackRef;
        private IList<Employee> _Subordinates;
        private IList<BusinessPartner> _BusinessPartners;

        public virtual string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set { _Name = value; }
        }

        public virtual string Position
        {
            get { return _Position; }
            set { _Position = value; }
        }

        public virtual Employee SupervisorBackRef
        {
            get { return _SupervisorBackRef; }
            set { _SupervisorBackRef = value; }
        }

        public virtual IList<Employee> Subordinates
        {
            get { return _Subordinates; }
            set { _Subordinates = value; }
        }

        public virtual IList<BusinessPartner> BusinessPartners
        {
            get { return _BusinessPartners; }
            set { _BusinessPartners = value; }
        }
    }
```

Because back reference SupervisorBackRef and Subordinates share same foreign key:

```
create table Employees (
        Id INT not null,
       Name NVARCHAR(255) null,
       Position NVARCHAR(255) null,
       EmployeeFk INT null,
       primary key (Id)
    )
```

Problem is that although I tryed override it, if I delete any supervisor, it delete all his Subordinates. I tryed this:

```
class EmployeeOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Employee>
{
    public void Override(FluentNHibernate.Automapping.AutoMapping<Employee> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.Subordinates).Cascade.None();
        mapping.HasOne(x => x.SupervisorBackRef).Cascade.None();
    }
}
```

But it isn't work. I tryed it changed to different another combinations, i tryed this override delete, but nothing help.

If I delete any Employee, it delete all his Subordinates.

I don't know how can i recognize if this override function working.

From many texts on internet i understand that Cascade.None() should work, most people has opposite problem, deleting/updating/... don't work, so I'm really confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was, that I had in another place (in `HasManyConvention.Apply`) set in instance `Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()` and it was higher priority.

PS: I don't know if is beter similar post like that answered od deleted. For me it looks like a problem which I had more time in past, but it is variation on "I dont't know my own code..."